# sql: check if a substring is numeric and replace it

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, substring

In my table I have a column that contains an `json`:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "block1": {
        "aaa": "string",
        "bb": "1234567890"
    }
}
```

How to write a sql query that checks if the value of bb field is numeric and if it is, replace it with a string?

The result would be like:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "block1": {
        "aaa": "string",
        "bb": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Please note that the `json` may contain other blocks before the block1.

I am using `SQL server 2014`.

Comment: Do you have a SQL to just extract and return the value of the `bb` field? If yes, then you use T-SQL's [`ISNUMERIC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) function to check if it can be interpreted as a number, and then use T-SQL's [string functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) to perform the replacement (i.e. cut the string in a left and right part before/after the value and concatenate them back together).

Comment: no, I don't have a query to extract this value

Comment: [This article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) may be useful. You can do the checks after converting it to a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query is quite lengthy, because it contains various fields in the outer select statement used to demonstrate the working of the query. To just get a working query, the select statement requires only the rightmost column (i.e. the `CASE ... END` statement).

**Objective**

> Write a SQL query that checks if the value of the bb field is numeric and if it is, replace it with a string.

**The SQL Query**

Each column in the outer query below shows a progressive step in fulfilling the objective, and those steps are explained below.

**Note**: To just get a working query, the select statement requires only the rightmost column (i.e. the `CASE ... END` statement). All the other columns are not required.

```
SELECT 
    json 
  -- Find the position of the JSON tag "bb": " 
  , PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) 
  -- Return the JSON data to the right of the JSON tag (right-half of the JSON) 
  , RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1) 
  -- Find the first double-quote from the right-half of the JSON 
  , PATINDEX(
        '%"%', 
        RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1)
    ) 
  -- Return the value of the JSON tag "bb" based on the position of the double-quote found above 
  , LEFT(
        RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1), 
        PATINDEX(
            '%"%', 
            RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1) 
        ) - 1 
    ) 
  -- Check if the above value is numeric or not 
  , ISNUMERIC( 
        LEFT(
            RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1), 
            PATINDEX('%"%', RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1)) - 1 
        )
    ) 
  -- Note: Only the following CASE expression is required, the previous expressions above were only to demonstrate the workings of the query 
  , CASE WHEN 
      ISNUMERIC( 
        LEFT(
            RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1), 
            PATINDEX('%"%', RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1)) - 1 
        )
      ) = 1 
    THEN 
      -- The value is numeric, replace the value with 'replacetext' 
      STUFF(
        json, 
        PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) + jsontaglength, 
        LEN( 
          LEFT(
              RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1), 
              PATINDEX('%"%', RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1)) - 1 
          )
        ), 
        replacetext
      ) 
    ELSE json 
    END as OutputJson 
FROM ( 
  -- Sample data for demonstration purposes 
  -- Two JSON blocks, one where the field bb is numeric, one where it is not 
    SELECT 
    '{
        "field1": "value1",
        "block1": {
            "aaa": "string",
            "bb": "1234567890"
        }
    }' AS json 
    -- This expression is the string 
    -- %"bb": " 
    -- and is used for pattern matching 
    , '%' + '"bb": "' + '%' AS jsontagpattern 
    -- The length of the string used in pattern matching 
    , LEN(  '"bb": "'     ) AS jsontaglength 
    -- If the value of bb is numeric, replace it with the following text 
    , 'XXXX'                AS replacetext 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
    '{
        "field1": "value1",
        "block1": {
            "aaa": "string",
            "bb": "1a23456789b0"
        }
    }' AS json 
    , '%' + '"bb": "' + '%' AS jsontagpattern 
    , LEN(  '"bb": "'     ) AS jsontaglength 
    , 'XXXX'                AS replacetext 
  ) AS x
```

**Explanation**

1. The first step is to find the position of the `bb` tag. This is done by the [`PATINDEX()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx):

   `PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json)`
2. The next step is to find the part of the JSON data that is to the right of the tag, as this will begin with the bb field's value.

   `RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1)`
3. From the string returned above, find the first double quote, as it indicates where the value of bb ends:

   `PATINDEX(
       '%"%', 
       RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1)
   )`
4. Get the value of the JSON field bb with the following (this returns 1234567890, for example):

   `LEFT(
       RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1), 
       PATINDEX(
           '%"%', 
           RIGHT(json, LEN(json) - PATINDEX(jsontagpattern, json) - jsontaglength + 1) 
       ) - 1 
   )`
5. Apply the [`ISNUMERIC()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) to the above value. It returns 1 if it is numeric, 0 otherwise.
6. If `ISNUMERIC()` returns 0, then return the original JSON data. However, if `ISNUMERIC()` returns 1, then replace the value of the `bb` field using the [`STUFF()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx).

**Sample Input & Output**

Given the following input:

```
{
        "field1": "value1",
        "block1": {
            "aaa": "string",
            "bb": "1234567890"       <----- Numeric value 
        }
    }
{
        "field1": "value2",
        "block1": {
            "aaa": "string",
            "bb": "1a23456789b0"     <----- Non-numeric value 
        }
    }
```

The output returned is:

```
{
        "field1": "value1",
        "block1": {
            "aaa": "string",
            "bb": "XXXX"             <----- Numeric value replaced by string 
        }
    }
{
        "field1": "value2",
        "block1": {
            "aaa": "string",
            "bb": "1a23456789b0"     <----- Non-numeric value unchanged 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this to be a challenging task, so here goes:

First, create a function that returns the values for bb:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_getBB(@str NVARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret NVARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @ret = (LEFT(RIGHT(@str,len(@str) - CHARINDEX('"bb": ', @str) - 6),        CHARINDEX('"',RIGHT(@str,len(@str) - CHARINDEX('"bb": ', @str) - 7),2)))
RETURN @ret;
END
```

It can be done without it, but it becomes unreadable, to say the least.

After that, you can test it like this:

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(1000)
SET @str = 'whatevertexthere "bb": "1237777" whateverothertextherexxx'

SELECT REPLACE(@str, '"bb": "'+dbo.fn_getBB(@str)+'"','"bb": "'+ 'ana are mere"')
WHERE ISNUMERIC(dbo.fn_getBB(@str)) = 1
```

If the tests look ok, simply run an `UPDATE` on your table with the same `WHERE` clause (`WHERE ISNUMERIC(dbo.fn_getBB(@str)) = 1`)

Hope it helps!

PS - the function assumes that there is always a "bb" in your JSON. If that's not the case, you can always supply it as a condition in your `WHERE` clause.

PPS - if you don't want to update the table but simply replace the value for bb in your resultset, use `SELECT CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(fn_getBB(yourjsoncol)) = 1 THEN REPLACE ... ELSE yourjsoncol ...`.